# How to import French characters from .txt file into a PDF form?

Tags: pdf, import, csv

We export information out of our CRM (via a tab delimited text file) and import the data into a PDF form. This process used to work but recently any French characters in the text file do not import into the PDF——it turns into a jumbled mess of characters.

Adobe has said it could be a bug but there's been no resolution yet.

I'm thinking it might be an issue of setting the files with the correct format/unicode. I can supply example files.

---

Step 1: we export the information as a .csv file (French characters intact)

Step 2: Save the .csv file as Tab Delimited Text (.txt) (French characters intact)

Step 3: In the PDF, import data selecting the .txt file. (French characters get jumbled)

Comment: Which font have you selected for the form fields?

Comment: Helvetica. We are able to manually type french characters into the fields but when we import data, the french characters turn into random symbols.

Our PDF has 200+ fields,and to manually have to review/change them all is very time-consuming—this process used to work prior to an update about 6 months ago

Comment: There are tons of Helvetica variations floating around. I do have comparable effects occasionally. Just as a test, try using Arial for the form fields.